# Querying an Open Source Dictionary & Thesaurus

Tags: open-source, dictionary, thesaurus, wiktionary

I'm developing an application & I'm hoping to be able to query words in real time from a dictionary & thesaurus stored on a database. Has anyone heard of any open source software (dictionaries) that can get this done? I'm thinking of trying to use Wiktionary/Wikisaurus & maybe put them in a SQL database and query for certain entries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider these tools:

http://code.google.com/p/wikokit/

http://www.ukp.tu-darmstadt.de/software/jwktl/